# A 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, jquery, server

When I use `window.location` or `window.location.href` or `location.reload` in my page inside the script i got this following Error in server but It's works fine in my local..

Error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /sample/admin/master.php on this server. Additionally,
>   a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This may issue with file permission. Have you used .htaccess?

Comment: Check the file permissions: Is the Webserver allowed to read the file?

Comment: file has this permission (rw-r-r) and owner 2444 @PankajMakwana

Comment: file has following permissions owner - r,w Group - r, Others - r@TobiasF.

Comment: Try changing permission to 0644

Comment: already file has 0644 permission@PankajMakwana

Comment: what is the directory permission?

Comment: 2444 for directory Permission@PankajMakwana

Comment: is this `rwxr-xr-x` directory permission?

Comment: Yes correct@PankajMakwana

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.